# Get the word under cursor in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to make a `tooltip`/`popup` for each word in textarea

So is it possible to get a word under cursor in textarea using `JavaScript` or `JQuery`?

All i have from event arguments (`mousemove`, `hover`) is a location of cursor. (or maybe not?)

And is it a good idea to split text of `textarea` into array with theirs probable locations in `textarea`(using `width` and `height` of chars).

And then send a `tooltip` at cursor location?

Comment: What have you tried so far yourself?

Comment: too broad. please include an [mcve]

Comment: no tries. im just looking to find a probable solution of it. all i have is assumption in 4th paragraph, but maybe there is a better way

Comment: @SomeoneToKnow Well SO is not a coding service. You should combine a mix of "Search Google" with "Try yourself" and if you then run into trouble with your code, Then post it here.

Comment: I think that is an interesting question. How a `textarea` behaves is very platform-dependent. Even if you limit yourself to one specific browser then it is still very difficult. This form element is not meant to do that and does not offer useful functionality. That is why I suggest you use another way of presenting the text, like a `<div>`. (You may not be aware that you can set the attribute `contenteditable` to make it behave similar to a textarea) Wrapping each word in a `<span>` is what I would do.

Comment: @jayms That's it, `contenteditable`. i didnt know about it

Answer (score 0):

Although this question is too general, I can only provide such an answer which I hope it will help. I think using a `<textarea>` to do this is not good and you will need to write complicated code to achieve this. I suggest you ran a loop with JavaScript code, for every word in the text area and create a subDOM below it with a `<span>` for each word. There, you can bind each tooltip to each span element. You could also hide the textarea afterwards.

So, split the string of the textarea into separate words, use jQuery to create a span element for each one of them and append all those to another container.

Does it make sense?